# How writing list from servlet to .txt

Tags: java, servlets

I created servlet which roll 10 random values sort and print this value. This value are adding to LinkedList. How I can save data form LinkedList to file.txt when application will be closed. I try create file in servlet and write something but my code isn't  creating file.

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet NewServlet</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet NewServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        List<Integer> lista=(List<Integer>) this.getServletContext().getAttribute("lista");
        out.println("<ul>");
        for(Integer l:lista){
            out.println("<li>"+l+"</li>");
        }
        out.println("</ul>");
        out.println("<form action=\"NewServlet1\">");
        out.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"liczba\">");
        out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"ADD\">");
        out.println("</form>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }

        PrintWriter zapis = null;
        zapis = new PrintWriter("test.txt");
        zapis.println("type type type ");
        zapis.close();


}
```

---

```
public class NewServletListener implements ServletContextListener {

static final public String defFileName = "file.txt";
String fileName;

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    List<Integer> lista=new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Random rand=new Random();
    int rozmiar=Integer.parseInt(sce.getServletContext().getInitParameter("rozmiar"));
    for(int i=0;i<rozmiar;i++){
        lista.add(rand.nextInt(100));
    }
    sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("lista", lista);

    fileName = sce.getServletContext().getInitParameter("SAVE_FILE");
    if (fileName == null) {
        fileName = defFileName;
    }
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
//        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        List<Integer> lista=(List<Integer>) sce.getServletContext().getAttribute("lista");

    File file = new File(fileName);
    try (PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file)) {
        for (Integer l:lista) {
            printWriter.println(l);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
}
```

It's strange but file does not create. Should I add to web.xml SAVE_FILE? or I do something else wrong.
File should create when i close overlap?

Comment: There is a slight divergence between the what you say *servlet which roll 10 random values sort and print this value* and code you show : *get a list from a `ServletContext` attribute and display it*. Do you want to save after each request, or when application stops (assuming you want to save `lista`) ?

Comment: When application stops

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I assume you compute somewhere in the web application a `List<String>` stored as a servlet context attribute with the name `"lista"`. You want to save it when application stops to a text file, one string per line.

You have to use a `ContextLoaderListener`. Assuming you use a servlet 3.0+ container you can register it with annotations (if not, you would have to register it in the deployment descriptor `web.xml`. You simply write the file in the `onDestroy` method :

```
@WebListener
public class SaveListener implements ServletContextListener {
    static final public String defFileName = "file.txt";
    String fileName;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // allow to find the name of the file in init parameters
        fileName = sce.getServletContext().getInitParameter("SAVE_FILE");
        if (fileName == null) {
            fileName = defFileName;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        List<String> lista = (List<String>) sce.getServletContext()
                .getAttribute("lista");
        File file = new File(fileName);
        try (PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file)) {
            for (String string : lista) {
                printWriter.println(string);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```